# How can I solve the spring ambiguity problem in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller

**dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="urlHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="/testlistCustomer.htm">supplierController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerController" class="com.debasish.spring.mvc.CustomerController">
</bean>

<bean id="supplierController" parent="customerController" class="com.debasish.spring.mvc.SupplierController">
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
     <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
     <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

**CustomerController

```
    public class CustomerController extends MultiActionController{
    
    public ModelAndView testlistCustomer(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        
        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","list() method in CustomerControler");
            
    }
  }
```

**SupplierController

```
public class SupplierController extends CustomerController{

    @Override
    public ModelAndView testlistCustomer(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","list() method in SupplierController ");
    }
}
```

**Spring framework version : 4.3.23.RELEASE**
Server started and I'm able to access below url

```
http://localhost:8084/spring.mvc/testlistCustomer.htm
```

I am getting ambiguity exception When I am implementing similar functionality in annotation based application.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Provide support for component scanning -->  
<context:component-scan base-package="spring.mvc.annotation" />  

<!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
<mvc:annotation-driven/>  

<bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
     <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
     <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

**CustomerController

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping
public class CustomerController{
    
    @GetMapping(path="/testlistCustomer.htm")
    public ModelAndView testlistCustomer(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
                
        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg",
                "list() method" );
                    
    }
    
}
```

**SupplierController

```
@Controller
public class SupplierController extends CustomerController{
    
    @Override
    public ModelAndView testalistCustomer(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        
        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg",
                "list() method in supplier controller");
            
    }

}
```

When starting the server I am getting below exception

```
    Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'supplierController' method 
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.SupplierController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
to {GET /testupdateCustomer.htm}: There is already 'customerController' bean method
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.CustomerController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'supplierController' method 
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.SupplierController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
to {GET /testupdateCustomer.htm}: There is already 'customerController' bean method
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.CustomerController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'supplierController' method 
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.SupplierController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
to {GET /testupdateCustomer.htm}: There is already 'customerController' bean method
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.CustomerController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:603)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:378)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:288)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:258)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:217)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    ... 21 more

Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'supplierController' method 
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.SupplierController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
to {GET /testupdateCustomer.htm}: There is already 'customerController' bean method
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.CustomerController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'supplierController' method 
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.SupplierController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
to {GET /testupdateCustomer.htm}: There is already 'customerController' bean method
com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation.controller.CustomerController#testupdateCustomer(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.validateMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:603)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:378)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:288)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:258)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:217)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    ... 21 more

Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/com.debasish.spring.mvc.annotation] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 10, 2020 1:32:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9732 ms
```

**Spring framework version : 5.2.8.RELEASE**
How Can I resolve this ambiguity problem and I want to access the same url which I mentioned above?

Comment: YOu cannot have 2 endpoints for a single URL... That simply isn't possible, why would you need 2 endpoints for the same URL?

Comment: I want to some extra functionality in Supplier class over Customer class in 2 separate application.. I can Run 2 separation application as per my requirement. For that xml based mvc working fine

Comment: because there you are effectivly are using only 1 controller and not 2. Only 1 is mapped to a URL.

Comment: Application one has some functionality which has common for both the application. on top of application 2 has some extra functionality. That's why I am injecting application1 into application2 and inherit the application1 contoller.

Comment: Please read. You are extending **BUT** effectivly are only using a single controller at runtime. With annotations you now have 2 controllers at runtime due to how annotations based MVC works.